# Rails FactoryBot uninitialized constant Mentor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I use Rails 5 with ruby 2.4.1

I begin make rspec tests on application...

This is my first test and i don't have success

After I will use Faker gem to put random information, but first i need this run with sucess, please help me!

spec_helper.rb

```rb
require 'factory_bot_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.before(:all) do
    FactoryBot.reload
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

factories.rb

```rb
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :plan do
    name { "Plano Livre" }
    nickname { "plano_livre" }
    price { 1000 }
    modules { ["Dataminer","Events", "Jobs", "RoomReservation", "Mentoring", "News", "Visitors", "Packages", "RocketChat", "Education", "StartupReview", "CorporateChallenges", "News", "Benefits", "HubDigital", "DigitalHub"] }
  end

  factory :user do
    name { "Orville Gibson" }
    email { "orville_gibson@mailinator.com" }
    password { "Teste123" }
    password_confirmation { "Teste123" }
    role { "admin" }
    plan { association :plan }
  end

  factory :mentor do
    user { association :user }
    time_band_init { "8:00" }
    time_band_end { "18:00" }
    mini_bio { "Thomas Cruise Mapother IV é um ator e produtor de cinema norte-americano de origem irlandesa." }
    mentoring_types { ["online"] }
  end

end
```

mentor_controller_spec.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'


describe 'Mentoring::MentorController' do
  before do
    @mentor = build(:mentor)
  end

  context 'GET dashboard' do
    it 'returns a 200' do
      get :mentor_dashboard_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end

end
```

EDIT 1:
app/models/
[image]

EDIT 2:
app/models/mentor.rb (begin of file)

```
class Mentor < ApplicationRecord
```

EDIT 3:
[Mentor.new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8H2V.png)

EDIT4:
[Mentor.new env=test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI2nW.png)

When I run rspec on console i have this error:

```
 1) Mentoring::MentorController GET dashboard returns a 200
 Failure/Error: @mentor = build(:mentor)
 
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Mentor
   Did you mean?  Monitor
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:68:in `constantize'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/factory_bot-5.2.0/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:26:in `build_class'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/factory_bot-5.2.0/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:37:in `run'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/factory_bot-5.2.0/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/factory_bot-5.2.0/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /home/jhonny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@distrito/gems/factory_bot-5.2.0/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:28:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/mentoring/mentor_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: `factory :mentor do` will try to make a Mentor object. Is there a Mentor class?

Comment: can you show content of `app/models/`?
and add it to the question

Comment: Ready, i add models folder print screen

Comment: Yes, Mentor Class have on Model @Schwern

Comment: @zhisme I edit with the model folder image

Comment: @AllanJhonny What happens if you try `Mentor.new`? If that works, something is wrong with FactoryBot. What if you `require 'mentor'` first? If it works after a `require` it's probably an [autoloading problem](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). Check in a Rails console. If it works in console, check your test vs development configuration.

Comment: @Schwern EDIT 3 Mentor.new

Comment: @Schwern When add require_relative '../../../app/models/mentor' test show error: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord

Comment: @AllanJhonny You shouldn't have to `require_relative`, `require 'mentor'` should work. `app/models` should be in your load path. If ApplicationRecord is not already loaded I think something is very wrong with your configuration. If `Mentor.new` works in console, something is wrong with your test configuration.

Comment: @AllanJhonny Try `RAILS_ENV=test rails console` to load a console using the test environment. Then try `Mentor.new`. If it can't find Mentor that will be easier to debug than through rspec. Look at `config/environments/test.rb` vs the other environments.

Comment: @Schwern added print on Edit 4, but the error on rspec is same :(

Comment: @AllanJhonny It was staring us in the face all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `require 'rails_helper'` in your rspec tests, not spec_helper.

rails_helper will set up the rails environment for `rspec` and load spec_helper, but spec_helper does not load rails_helper. Without rails_helper, rspec does not know how to load the Rails code.

Comment: Thanks for help me, now I have another problems, but I will search for anothers erros, thnaks!